# Annotation don't show in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm using `vue-chartjs`. I need annotations in my charts.
I'm imported an annotation plugin

```js
import chartjsPluginAnnotation from "chartjs-plugin-annotation"
```

Then add a plugin on mounted

```js
this.addPlugin(chartjsPluginAnnotation)
```

Also, I added an annotation object to the options

```
plugins: {
  annotation: {
          drawTime: 'afterDraw',
            annotations: [
              {
                type: "line",
                id: 'BTV',
                mode: "horizontal",
                display: true,
                scaleID: "y-axis-0",
                borderColor: "red",
                value: 17000,
                borderDash: 4,
                label: {
                  content: 'aa',
                  enabled: true,
                  position: "top",
                  xAdjust: 15,
                  backgroundColor: '#4ecca3',
                  fontSize: 10,
                }
              }
          ]
  },
}
```

It works in all manuals what I find, but doesn't work in my project

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the "chart.js" v2.9.4(latest), just DOWNGRADE it to v2.9.3 . Maybe they have some issues on that version.

Please check my "package.json" below.

```
"dependencies": {
  "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
  "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
  "vue": "^2.6.11",
  "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1" 
}
```

It works properly for me.

Comment: use "chart.js": "2.9.3" 
not "chart.js": "^2.9.3"

Answer (score 7):

One problem I see is that you've defined `annotation` under `plugins` whereas it should be defined *directly* under `options`. (I know this is confusing, because some of the chartjs-annotation-plugin documentation still shows an example with `annotation` as a property of `plugins` rather than `options`.)

There is, however, another issue which does appear to stem from a change that was made in Chart.js 2.9.4. [The method of cloning an object was modified](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/7404/commits/bbb9c9882de018ae2844145a9fca362190a510aa#diff-94c3811674c4e6e5f288be72ca1e76d4c2376031545ceb90e03f797516dfbe5f), such that it now utilizes [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), which copies the properties from the source object into the target object's *prototype*. The problem, in the context of a Vue app, is that the `options` that you pass to the [`renderChart()`](https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#renderchart) method is very likely a Vue observer (e.g., a prop or a member of `data`), which means that *its* properties are all set (by Vue, under the hood) using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Here's why that is important:

> Setting a property to an object creates an own property. **The only exception** to the getting and setting behavior rules is when there is an inherited property with a getter or a setter.

(From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

The reason this is a problem is that, when Chart.js initializes a chart, it creates the options by recursively merging your configuration options with a bunch of global defaults; part of this merging behavior involves the aforementioned cloning if the property is a non-standard option, which will render your `annotation` object with its properties copied to its prototype, but with no properties of its own. Therefore, when the annotation plugin is initialized, it finds an annotation object, but one without any properties of its own, and when the annotation plugin initializes *its* configuration, it merges your `annotation` object with *its* defaults - which includes an empty `annotations` array.

It seems to me that downgrading Chart.js to 2.9.3 should work for you, provided that you also move your `annotation` property from `plugins` to directly under `options`. An alternative - if you want to continue using the latest version of Chart.js - is to ensure that the options you pass to the `renderChart()` method are non-reactive (that is, not a Vue observer). One way to accomplish that would be to copy your reactive `annotation` object's properties into a POJO (Plain Old Javascript Object), e.g., by using `Object.assign()`:

```
this.renderChart(this.chartData, { 
  ...this.options, 
  annotation: Object.assign({}, this.options.annotation) 
})
```

I have filed an issue on the Chart.js GitHub: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8382